# Demons sealed in WWII Sherman tanks are released years later

Tags: story-identification, books, demons

I read part of this book in the 1980s, so it is at least that old.  The story was based on 13 WWII black Sherman tanks abandoned in a field somewhere that had their hatches welded shut (and I believe they had a crucifix on the hatch as well).  Years after the war, people open the hatches and find the inside empty except for a cloth sack.  Then things started to happen...

I put the book down then and never finished it but for some reason it popped into my head recently and I was wondering what the title was.  Another aspect of the book that I recall was that incantations (to summon a demon) were authentic and the author in the preface strongly discouraged the reader from reading them out loud.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This has to be [*The Devils of D-Day*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?483221) (1978) by Graham Masterton.

Quoting the blurb:

> At the bridge of Le Vey in July 1944, **thirteen black tanks** smashed through the German lines in an unstoppable, all-destroying fury ride. Leaving hundreds of Hitler’s soldiers horribly dead.
>
> Thirty-five years later, Dan McCook visited that area of Normandy on an investigation of the battle site. There he found a rusting tank by the roadside that was perfectly sealed, **upon its turret a protective crucifix**. Sceptical, he dared open it, releasing upon himself and the innocents who had helped him an unimaginable horror that led back to that black day in 1944. And re-opened the ages-old physical battle between the world and Evil Incarnate...

I found [a review](http://www.fantasyliterature.com/reviews/the-devils-of-d-day/) that quotes the warning you were mentioning:

> *All the devils and demons that appear in this book are legendary creatures of hell, and there is substantial recorded evidence for their existence. For that reason, **it is probably inadvisable to attempt to conjure up any of them by repeating out loud the summons used in the text, which are also genuine**. I would like to point out that the Pentagon and the British Ministry of Defense strenuously deny the events described here, but I leave it to you to draw your own conclusions.* – from the Author’s Note

There are a lot more quotes and details at the linked review; I'm positive it's the book you're looking for.

[image: Cover of "The Devils of D-Day"]

Comment: Jinx! :) I'm perfectly fine with ceding to you.

Comment: I thought the Germans were the Bad Guys? And here I see allies harnessing actual Satanic Forces (above and beyond the satanic forces that were actually unleashed, that is). A pyhrric victory, that is.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer That's actually part of the plot of the book - how high-level commanders were willing to use blatantly evil means to win (like firebombing civilian populations) and how mid-level commanders used euphemisms and mission-focused tunnel vision and the like to avoid confronting what they were doing.